# how to calculate distance between 2 Tensors using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

do you have any suggetion on how to calculate distance between two tensors?
(I am considering "frobenius norm" and "cosine similarity", do you think these two are good aproaches?).Thanks

Comment: Have you tried and compared any of the norms yourself already?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what do you want to achieve by getting the distance. You should add more context to your question so that people can answer concretely.
One way to calculate some "distance" for tensors `x` and `y` is to:

```
tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(x - y), 1))
```

Frebenius norm is usually used for one vector/tensor, but it's similar to the above code - it sums the squares and applies a square root to that sum.

Cosine similarity is traditionally used as a measure of similarity between two texts, so I wouldn't recommend it out of the blue.

Comment: I am investigating the bottleneck of an Autoencoder, trained to learn different simple objects. I want to enforce different parts of the bottleneck to learn different traits of the object. To evaluate the network I am trying to compare the tensors(shape of tensor is 8x8x2) in the bottleneck for different objects.  How to compare?  Maybe calculate the norm of the difference between 2 tensors and expect a high value for different objects and low value for similar objects. Currently I am using      np.average(np.square(x-y))    ,which returns a single value, not sure its appropriate

Comment: I will try your approach